# How to disable CustomValidator for a specific scenario

Tags: java, validation, gwt, smartgwt

I have a form which uses CustomValidator to check for non empty field whenever we try to Add a record `(PARAMETER, VALUE)`
I'm looking for a way to disable form validation when I'm trying to Delete (the user can delete an empty `listGridRecord` if he changes his mind and needs no more to add).

I'm using this custom validator:

```
    CustomValidator validatorParameter = new CustomValidator() {

        @Override
        protected boolean condition(Object value) {

            parameterName = (String) value;
            if ((value == null || ((String) value).trim().isEmpty())) {
                rowIsValidate = false;
                return false;
            } else {
                rowIsValidate = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
```

which I'm setting in an `init()` method this way:

```
parametersListGrid.getField(PARAMETER).setValidators(validatorParameter);
```

I tried setting a flag "`noValidation`" on true whenever I detect a click on Delete button and used it this way:

```
CustomValidator validatorParameter = new CustomValidator() {

        @Override
        protected boolean condition(Object value) {

            parameterName = (String) value;
            if (((value == null || ((String) value).trim().isEmpty())) && !noValidation){
                rowIsValidate = false;
                return false;
            } else {
                rowIsValidate = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
```

but I figured out that this flag is set later on after the validation happened so 
`rowIsValidate` stays false and we can't delete the empty record given the errors shown after validation;

Any idea on how to pass this validation step just in deletion scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `discardEdits(rowNum)` before deleting a record.

Same question is  asked on [SmartClient Forums](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=21078).